# Image ignoring 'zIndex' instruction from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, css

I have a many rows of images which normally have z-index values rising the further down the page they are. However for some items I would like them to have a lower z-index than the rest (except on hover). The items are images inside their down individual divs. The problem is that the zIndex command sees to be ignored. I have made a fiddle which shows the problem [SEE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4bL9e5pc/1/). If you click both the divs, then, after moving the cursor away, the top left image should move in front of the bottom right one, but it doesn't.
I have tried making all images and divs position relative, but that isn't working.

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="r1d allCells" id="c0001" onclick="populateCell(this.id,'https://www.netcetra.com/images/howto_images/picmonkey-logo.jpg')"><img class="cellimg" id="ic0001" src=""></div>

  <div class="r1d allCells" id="c0002" onclick="populateCell(this.id,'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e3/d2/76/e3d2762c850323a8a5ac6c4327026c2b.jpg')"><img class="cellimg" id="ic0002" src=""></div>

</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
}

.r1d:nth-child(odd) {
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
}

.r1d:nth-child(even) {
  z-index: 101;
  margin: 1.7rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
}

.wrapScroll img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skewX(30deg) rotate(-30deg);
  min-width: 5rem;
  max-width: 5rem;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  /*new to try and fix z-index issues with roads */
}

.wrapScroll img[src*="100-500"],
.wrapScroll img[src*="construction"] {
  margin: -21.3rem 0 0 -12.6rem;
}

.allCells:hover {
  z-index: 300;
}

.allCells:hover~img {
  /* change selector to all images   */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* opacity: 0; not sure what this is here for */
}

.allCells:hover>img {
  z-index: 301;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #222;
}

.allCells {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: double rgba(107, 50, 4, 0.4) .5rem;
  background: rgb(65, 143, 19, 0.4) .2rem;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  max-height: 2.6rem;
  max-width: 3rem;
  min-height: 2.6rem;
  min-width: 3rem;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 60;
  /*new to try and fix z-index issues with roads */
  /*cursor: url(images/cursorWrench.png), auto;*/
}

.allCells:hover {
  border: solid rgb(255, 148, 26) .2rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```
function populateCell(clicked_id, selectedItemCache2) {
  var clicked_id2 = "i" + clicked_id;
  document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = 'black';
  pauseBuild([clicked_id], [clicked_id2], [selectedItemCache2]);
}

function pauseBuild(pause, pause2, pause3) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(pause2).src = pause3;
    if (pause3.indexOf("originals") >= 0) {
      document.getElementById(pause).style.zIndex = '10';
      document.getElementById(pause2).style.zIndex = '10';
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: your code never gets to the part where it applies the `z-index`. its stuck at this line `if (pause3.indexOf("originals") >= 0) {`

Comment: i changed that line into ` if (pause3.indexOf("originals") != null) {` but doing so makes it apply z-index to your images no matter what. wich means this still needs some tweaking

Comment: Any ideas why is it not getting past the 'if' statement? I have used the indexOf elsewhere the in the full code to change other properties for the same element, and it has worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

it turns out `pause3` is an array.

if you edit your if statement like this: `if (pause3[0].indexOf("originals") >= 0)` it will work:

```js
function populateCell(clicked_id, selectedItemCache2) {
  var clicked_id2 = "i" + clicked_id;
  document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = 'black';
  pauseBuild([clicked_id], [clicked_id2], [selectedItemCache2]);
}

function pauseBuild(pause, pause2, pause3) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(pause2).src = pause3;
    if (pause3[0].indexOf("originals") >= 0) {
      document.getElementById(pause).style.zIndex = '10';
      document.getElementById(pause2).style.zIndex = '10';
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
}

.r1d:nth-child(odd) {
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
}

.r1d:nth-child(even) {
  z-index: 101;
  margin: 1.7rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
}

.wrapScroll img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skewX(30deg) rotate(-30deg);
  min-width: 5rem;
  max-width: 5rem;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  /*new to try and fix z-index issues with roads */
}

.wrapScroll img[src*="100-500"],
.wrapScroll img[src*="construction"] {
  margin: -21.3rem 0 0 -12.6rem;
}

.allCells:hover {
  z-index: 300;
}

.allCells:hover~img {
  /* change selector to all images   */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* opacity: 0; not sure what this is here for */
}

.allCells:hover>img {
  z-index: 301;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #222;
}

.allCells {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: double rgba(107, 50, 4, 0.4) .5rem;
  background: rgb(65, 143, 19, 0.4) .2rem;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  max-height: 2.6rem;
  max-width: 3rem;
  min-height: 2.6rem;
  min-width: 3rem;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 60;
  /*new to try and fix z-index issues with roads */
  /*cursor: url(images/cursorWrench.png), auto;*/
}

.allCells:hover {
  border: solid rgb(255, 148, 26) .2rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="r1d allCells" id="c0001" onclick="populateCell(this.id,'https://www.netcetra.com/images/howto_images/picmonkey-logo.jpg')"><img class="cellimg" id="ic0001" src=""></div>

  <div class="r1d allCells" id="c0002" onclick="populateCell(this.id,'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e3/d2/76/e3d2762c850323a8a5ac6c4327026c2b.jpg')"><img class="cellimg" id="ic0002" src=""></div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's great thanks, it's working now. Two questions: 1. How did you figure out this was an array? (i.e. what was your process to debug).   2. Does passing a variable which contains a text string inside these [] brackets, from 1 function to another, convert it to an array?  (I didn't need to treat the contents of this variable as an array when I called it within it's birth function in my full code).

Comment: i console logged pause3 right above the if statement, wich gave an output like: `["https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e3/d2/76/e3d2762c850323a8a5ac6c4327026c2b.jpg"]` here the [] quotes indicate it is in an array

Comment: passing values from function to function does not turn it into an array by default. its depending on what you do with the string. in this case: indexOf() was used and this return's an array by default take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp